# Angular: Programatically set style of complex css selector

Tags: angular, renderer

I'm looking for a way to do the following programatically:

```
tr.product-row:not(.expanded-row):active {
   background-color: red; <--this part will be calculated in my .ts file
}
```

The reason is that I want the active color to be a lighter version of the color of a different element.
I can calculate the color I need but don't know how to set it.

Can it be done with Renderer2?

Comment: Are you using SASS? If so perhaps `lighten()` function would suit your need. If you're using just CSS, you can try `filter: brightness();`

Comment: @penleychan I can't use sass or css because I want the user of the component to be able define the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using CSS variables which you can bind to in templates:

CSS:

```
tr.product-row:not(.expanded-row):active {
   background-color: var(--some-var); // specify some variable
}
```

Template:

```
<!-- bind to that variable using directive against component property -->
<div [style.--some-var]="theVariableInComponentFile">foobar</div>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v8wefv?file=src/app/app.component.html) of binding to a CSS variable in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks./ your stackblitz isn't loading but the I got  enough info from your answer. That's a cool trick that I didn't know about. Cheers.

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight I updated the [url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v8wefv?file=src/app/app.component.html), hopefully that works now.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done via directives with input value to them of the color you calculate
And then rendrer can be used to set the color you passed